# Using NEST to load data into ElasticSearch

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, elasticsearch, nest

My plan is to write custom C# code using NEST to load my data into ElasticSearch. What I need is some resources that would help me achieve my goal. Please suggest some if you can?
As far as I understand after I load MySql data to Elastic then I need to keep indexed data from Elastic up-to-date by using rivers, is this the only way, and what would be the best practice to keep Elastic updated?

Comment: A question you provide young padawan... Research you do not.

Comment: @MasterYoda I am in the process of research master Yoda

Comment: @BojanTomić there is no try only do. [Link](https://www.elastic.co/blog/deprecating-rivers)

Comment: I recommend looking at Logstash with the JDBC input plugin for this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html